# codeigniter data is not getting inserted in database

Tags: php, database, insert, codeigniter-2

Im a newbie in [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and I just followed a tutorial for CRUD operations within framework but my data is not getting inserted in my database. Here is my code:

Controller: site.php

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view("home");

  }
  function create()
  {
    $data=array('title'=>$this->input->post("title"),
        'song'=>$this->input->post("song")
        );
    $this->site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();
  }
}
```

View: home.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input,label
    {
      display:block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="content">Song:</label>
      <input type="text" name="song" id="song" />   
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Model: site_model.php

```
<?php
class site_model extends CI_Model
{
  function getAll()
  {
    $q=$this->db->get('name');
    return $q->result();
  }
  function add_record($data)
  {
    $this->db->insert("name",$data);
    return;
  }
  function update_record($data)
  {
    $this->db->where("id",14);
    $this->db->update('name',$data);
  }
  function delete_row($data)
  {
    $this->db->where("id",$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('name',$data);
  }
}
```

My table name is **name** and I have 3 fields: id(auto_increment), title, and song. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before you calling model function.

```
$this->load->model('site_model');
```

after that call your model function

```
$this->site_model->add_record($data);
```

I think this will solve your problem

Regards

iijb